# Prepostion at vs in, which is correct, "I am at my house" or "I am in my house"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Prepostion "at" vs "in", which is correct, "I am at my house" or "I am in my house"?

I tend to use "I am at my house" if for example I am calling a friend by phone (he is currently far from my house) and I happen to be inside my house and I think that I should use "I am in my house" if my friend that I'm calling by phone is just near my house or is just outside my house.

Comment: Why should it matter where your friend is when you're describing your location?

Comment: Both prepositions are 'correct'. You would use _at_ to indicate that you are at home and not in another place, and _in_ if you need to specify that you are indoors and not outside.

Comment: @Kate The most elegant answer I've seen in a long time. And restricted to a 'comment' (you villain) because it's not an ELU-standard question. You've made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, "at" means that you are in the vicinity of something, not necessarily inside it. For example, you might say "I have arrived at work" when you have reached the grounds but not yet entered the building. You can also use "at" when speaking about things other than buildings - for example, you could say "I'm at the bus stop".

However, "at home", or "at my house" are common idiomatic ways of stating your location. You could say "I'm at my house" and be outside in your garden, but nobody would assume that you weren't inside the house because you said 'at' and not 'in'.

For that reason, neither of your examples are wrong in this context, but "in" is the only preposition that *explicitly* says you are inside the building.

In a similar example, but with a different preposition, people say "I'm *at* the beach", which could mean they are actually sitting *on* the sand, or swimming in the sea, or at some attraction nearby. Only saying "I'm *on* the beach" explicitly means they are on the sand.

Comment: And when the kids have been naughty, 'Dad's _in_ the beach.'